# why controls inside a gridview (which is inside a user control) do not retain their properties' values after a postback?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a page that has 5 user controls of the same typ. Each user control has a gridview and a couple of buttons.

I don't understand why the controls on the user controls don't retain their value.

## EDIT

Below is how I'm populating the gridview inside a user control.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = new List<CKListByDprtment>
        {
            new CKListByDprtment { ID = 1, TaskName = "New laptop needed", 
            CompletedBy = "My Boss", HMReq = true },
            new CKListByDprtment { ID = 2, TaskName = "New Workstation needed",
            CompletedBy = "My Boss", HMReq = false }
        };

        gvCKList.DataSource = list;
        gvCKList.DataBind();        

    }
    #endregion

    #region GridView Validation
    protected void cvValidateGrid_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        ValidateGrid();
    }

    private void ValidateGrid()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvCKList.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox ckHMreq = gvRow.Cells[0].FindControl("ckHMreq") as CheckBox;
        }
    }
```

I tried to add a checkbox on the main aspx page. When the page posted back, the checked was able to retain its value. I tried also on the user control but not inside the gridview. When the postback, the checkbox retained its value.

It looks like only inside the gridview where controls lose their values after a postback. I have added **ViewStateMode = "Enabled"** first on the aspx page, then on the usercontrol and finaly on the gridview itself, but with no success.

Any reason?

Comment: Are you adding the user controls dynamically in the code-behind or are they present in the aspx page?

Comment: They are present in the aspx page

Comment: Where in the page lifecycle are you populating the user controls? I am wondering if the viewstate _is_ restored but maybe you are repopulating the data and it gets overwritten. Do you have `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` around the usercontrol population code?

Comment: No. I'm still building the pages. So I'm more focused on the validation (as you van see). There's just some lines of code to populate the gridview. See the EDIT for the code I'm using in the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that for every `PostBack` you are calling `DataBind()`. You should only call `DataBind()` if `Page.IsPostBack` equals `false`.

Comment: Make sens. Now it's retaining the values. I overlooked the fact that PageLoad happens before other event handlers enter into action.

Comment: The viewstate is restored before `Page_Load`. If you call `gvCKList.DataBind()` you are overwriting the grid's child controls. :)